# Cannot convert return expression of type 'MopubBannerAdView' to return type 'UIViewController?'

Tags: swift, swiftui, banner, mopub

Im trying to show mopubBanner in my swiftUI app and Im struggling with one of the delegate methods which I have to implement in the delegate. Im not sure if its possible to return a viewController here.

Not implementing this method results in the banner ad not being clickable.

```
import MoPub

struct MopubBannerAdView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return MopubBannerViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MPAdViewDelegate {
        
        private let parent: MopubBannerAdView
        
        init(_ mopubView: MopubBannerAdView) {
            self.parent = mopubView
        }
        
        func viewControllerForPresentingModalView() -> UIViewController! {
            return self.parent /// this line here throws the error
        }
    }
}
```

How can I best solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the presenting viewController and for that you can use the window rootVC e.g

```
  func viewControllerForPresentingModalView() -> UIViewController! {
       return  UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.rootViewController
   }
```